# Converting a list of nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and need to handle a nested objects response from the backend.

The response is of the below format:

```
    `0001
     :
     {title: "some value", aFlag: null, 
     cFlag: null, paramC: null, …}
     0002
     :
     {title: "some value", aFlag: null, 
     cFlag: null, paramC: null, …}
     0003`   
     :
     {title: "some value", aFlag: null, 
     cFlag: null, paramC: null, …}
     and so on
```

The values are not null in actual scenario. The numbers 0001, 0002 etc are the key which have key value pair objects as their object.

I need to display the value of "title" as a dropdown so need to iterate through the values and create an array of title. 
This is how far I have got:

```
$http.get("some endpoint")
 .then(function(response)
 {
 $scope.apiResp = response.data;


 for (var key in $scope.apiResp ) {
 $scope.titleList.push(createtitleList(key,$scope.apiResp[key]))
 }
 });

 function createtitleList(keyParam, valueParam){
 var tempObj = {
    aFlag : valueParam[keyParam].aFlag;  
    //same for rest of the params 
 }
 //return title value to add to the $scope.titleList array 
}
```

I am getting a syntax error when I try accessing the parameters of the object. How do I achieve this?

Here is the error which I get:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'aFlag' of undefined
at createtitleList(my-cntrl.js:54)
at my-cntrl.js:48
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing valid structure of the response. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have provided the response format as well as my code snippet - not sure what else is expected? @charlietfl

Comment: No you provided a syntactically invalid representation that nobody can use to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please find my edit above @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the error:

```
function createtitleList(keyParam, valueParam){
var tempObj = {
aFlag : valueParam.aFlag, 
//I was accessing the valueParam[keyParam] again which was throwing the Type error
//same for rest of the params 
}
 //return title value to add to the $scope.titleList array 
}
```

Hope this helps someone!